# A strategy to alter redux state with action in useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to implement a component that takes a phone number from the redux store, parses the number up on component load with `useEffect()`, puts the parsed elements (country code and ten digit number) into their own state with `useState()` and then on `onChange` of the phone form, update both sections of the number AND update the full phone prop coming from the redux store. I'm obviously not doing something right here:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { object, func, bool } from 'prop-types';
import { Row, Col } from 'styled-bootstrap-grid';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './BillingDetails.css';
import Button from 'components/Button';
import {
  setFirstName,
  setLastName,
  setPhone,
  setEmail,
} from '../../../store/signup/actions';

import {
  billingDetailsError,
  isValidInput,
  regExpValidations,
} from '../validateInput';

import InnerTitle from './InnerTitle';
import Input from './Input';
import PhoneInput from './PhoneInput';
import CountryCodeInput from './CountryCodeInput';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown';

const BillingDetails = ({ signup, onChange, onBlur, onNext, inputError }) => {
  const { first_name: firstName, last_name: lastName, email, phone } = signup;


  const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState('');
  const [mobileNumber, setMobileNumber] = useState('');

  // Parse the incoming phone prop into country code and the ten digit mobile phone. Sets separate state for both.
  useEffect(() => {
    const phoneArray = phone.split('');
    const cc = phoneArray.splice(0, phoneArray.length - 10).join('');
    setCountryCode(cc);
  }, '');

  useEffect(() => {
    const phoneArray = phone.split('');
    const tenDigitNumber = phoneArray.join('');
    setMobileNumber(tenDigitNumber);
  }, '');

  useEffect(() => {
    interpolatePhone();
  }, [countryCode, mobileNumber]);


  const interpolatePhone = () => {
    const fixedMobile = mobileNumber.replace(/[- )(]/g, '');
    const interpolatedPhone = `${countryCode}${fixedMobile}`;
    setPhone(interpolatedPhone);
  };

  // Onsubmit concatenates country code and mobile number, calls setPhone action with concat number and onNext().
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPhone(interpolatePhone());
    onNext();
  };
```

skipping to relevant JSX:

```
 <Col sm="12" md="12">
          <>
            <div className="phone-input">
              <Col sm="3" md="4">
                <CountryCodeInput
                  label="mobile number"
                  name="country_code"
                  onChange={e => setCountryCode(e.target.value)}
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  type="country_code"
                  value={countryCode}
                  inputValue={!countryCode ? '+1' : countryCode}
                  masked
                  error={
                    inputError && !isValidInput(phone, regExpValidations.phone)
                  }
                />
              </Col>
              <Col sm="1" md="1">
                |
              </Col>
              <Col sm="3" md="4">
                <PhoneInput
                  autoFocus
                  name="mobile_phone"
                  onChange={e => setMobileNumber(e.target.value)}
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  type="phone"
                  value={mobileNumber}
                  inputValue={mobileNumber}
                  masked
                  error={
                    inputError && !isValidInput(phone, regExpValidations.phone)
                  }
                />
              </Col>
            </div>
          </>
        </Col>
        <Button
          className="full-width"
          onClick={onSubmit}
          disabled={billingDetailsError(signup)}
        >
          Continue
        </Button>
   </Button>
      </Row>
    </Col>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  signup: state.signup,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BillingDetails);
```

Comment: What exactly your problem ? and I see the useEffect with empty string as dependencies, I think it should be empty array [].

Comment: I think, you should upload code of your action and reducer for `setPhone` for detecting your issue easier.

Comment: `phone` doesn't update. I